# How to position label under icon in Semantic UI-React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Im using Semantic UI-React. My question is how to position a label or text under an icon? There are only two default options which is left and right of the icon. However I want to position the label below the icon.
Im using Semantic-React library.

For example:

```
<Button icon labelPosition='left'>
  <Icon name='pause' />
  Pause
</Button>
```

In the above snippet the label 'Pause' is added on the left side of the icon in the button.
My requirement is, I want to add the label 'Pause below the icon in the button'. I tried setting the:

```
    labelPosition='down' or 'bottom'
```

However it does not work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem.
I believe that this could be done only by overriding the CSS properties of the Button element.
Please try providing `!important` to the CSS values, since semantic UI takes the highest priority when it comes to priority of the properties.

You can either use a class and define the style there, or else use a specific selector like this: `div.ui.stackable.two.column.grid.button{`.

Please let me know if this fixes, otherwise I have another solution to it.

Comment: I believe, this has to be done using pure CSS and not by any prop to the Button component. One other way is to extend the Button component provided by Semantic-React with custom CSS and use the customized Button component in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Put a line break between the icon and the text.

```
<Button icon>
  <Icon name='pause' />
  <br />
  Pause
</Button>
```

To change the amount of space between the icon and the text, you can add margin to the line break.

```
<Button icon>
  <Icon name='pause' />
  <br style={{marginBottom: '8px'}} />
  Pause
</Button>
```